# php date() diff() How to get a date with zeros?

Tags: php, date, diff, datediff

That get 
i use code:

```
$then = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $seconds_end));
$now = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));
$diff = $then->diff($now);
```

But in `var_dump($diff);` i see:

```
object(DateInterval)#4 (8) { 
                           ["y"]=> int(0) 
                           ["m"]=> int(0) 
                           ["d"]=> int(6) 
                           ["h"]=> int(2) 
                           ["i"]=> int(1) 
                           ["s"]=> int(17) 
                           ["invert"]=> int(1)
                           ["days"]=> int(6) 
                           }
```

Tell me please how get `y,m,d,h,i,s` with zeros, that ,ex., `$diff['h']` will be `'02'` instead of `'2'` ?

Comment: That is just how it represents it internally, when you format it you will get the leading zeros (if you use the correct format ofcourse).

Comment: @FruityP can give a simple?

Comment: echo sprintf('%02d', $diff->d). (check my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use "format" method of DateInterval:
http://php.net/manual/ru/dateinterval.format.php

eg:

```
$diff->format('%Y-%M-%D %H:%I:%S');
```

If you only want to get one of attributes, use sprintf or str_pad:

```
sprintf('%02d', $diff->d);

str_pad($$diff->d, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: **not worked** `$diff->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); object(DateInterval)#4 (8) { ["y"]=> int(0) ["m"]=> int(0) ["d"]=> int(6) ["h"]=> int(1) ["i"]=> int(42) ["s"]=> int(4) ["invert"]=> int(1) ["days"]=> int(6) }`

Comment: call var_dump on method result: var_dump($diff->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')), not the object itself.
It certainly works.

Comment: `string(11) "Y-m-d H:i:s"`

Comment: I'm sorry, "%Y-%M-%D %H:%I:%S"

Comment: **sorry but i make** `$diff->format('%Y-%M-%D %H:%I:%S');
var_dump($diff);` **i again get result** `object(DateInterval)#4 (8) { ["y"]=> int(0) ["m"]=> int(0) ["d"]=> int(6) ["h"]=> int(1) ["i"]=> int(28) ["s"]=> int(39) ["invert"]=> int(1) ["days"]=> int(6) }`...

Comment: And again, use $diff = $diff->format('%Y-%M-%D %H:%I:%S'); var_dump($diff);
You are calling "format" method, and var_dump'ing the object, instead of result.
Also I updated answer, check another way to do this.

Comment: but when i use `var_dump($diff->format('%Y-%M-%D %H:%I:%S'))` i get `string(17) "00-00-06 01:25:50"`... what problem can been?

Comment: -- what problem can been?
What do you want to achieve? If you need formatted string - this is the answer. If you need only one of parameters, use sprintf.

Comment: yes, im sorry, i not use sprintf('%02d', $diff->m) in result. all right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the string length if its not 2 then add a 0(zero) string, like follows

```
if(strlen($diff->h)==1) 
{
$new_hr='0'.$interval->h;   
}
echo $new_hr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few things wrong here. You don't need to use date() with [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) objects and [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is more appropriate for your use case. Your example code should look like this:-

```
$then = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $seconds_end);
$now = new DateTime(); // Defaults to current date & time
$diff = $then->diff($now);
```

Then you can output in any [format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) you wish:-

```
echo $diff->format("Time difference = %Y Years %M Months %D Days %H Hours %I Minutes %S Seconds");
```

Which will produce something like:-

```
Time difference = 00 Years 00 Months 06 Days 23 Hours 17 Minutes 38 Seconds
```